# Duplicate identifier 'DateAdapter' receiving in appModule

Tags: angular, import

In my project, I have imported following packages in my App.Module as I need to use both -

```
import { NativeDateAdapter, DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MatFormFieldModule,MatInputModule } from "@angular/material";
```

and

```
import { CalendarModule, DateAdapter } from 'angular-calendar';
```

As I am importing `DateAdapter` for the packages, it's giving me error as

> "Duplicate identifier 'DateAdapter'."

Can someone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Try using `import { CalendarModule, DateAdapter as DateAdapter2 } from 'angular-calendar';` where `DateAdapter2` may be any name that fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
import { CalendarModule, DateAdapter as DateAdapter2} from 'angular-calendar';
```